# Enforce max PHP script execution time to 5 secs

Tags: linux, php-fpm

I'm having a TERRIBLE problem in a dedicated server that's used as a Mobile App backend which has less than 1000 downloads.

There's a script (which is run multiple times a day) that hangs for a long time. I'm sure that it's because I'm Guzzling my own server with it's domain name and not a loopback address. Nevertheless this causes that when there's a very small amount of concurrent users, the server hangs forever until I restart Apache. This is of course not a hardware limitation issue since the user base is very small for a dedicated server.

Until I find the root cause of the problem, I need this to stop happening ASAP, so I must KILL any PHP Script that lasts longer than say 5/15 secs. The script must be killed immediately after that time elapses, otherwise this is going to keep happening and my client is already quite furious about this.

Kind regards, Joaquin.

Answer (score 0):

In your `php.ini` file (probably `/etc/php/<version>/fpm/php.ini`) you want to change the max_execution_time setting:

```
max_execution_time = 5
```

Then re-start php-fpm and the web server.